# Can the hero who goes last push a monster off the end of the momentum track?

Tags: thornwatch

On a test playthrough of Thornwatch, we had two heroes and a "Husk" on the Momentum track.

The Husk was in first position, and after it had done the actions for its 4 pawns, the Guard dealt it 1 damage, pushing it so the tracker was:

1. Guard (tapped)
2. Husk (tapped)
3. Sage

As I understand it, it is now the Sage's go, but even if their action dealt the Husk 8 damage, it would still only push the Husk to the end of the tracker, and everything would then reset, "wasting" the attack.

Thus I advised the Sage to "Plan" and go first next round. Was this good advice?

**Is it correct that, unless the monster is "on the edge" on the momentum tracker, the final hero of a round cannot kill it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is correct. See page 15 of the rules under 'Getting Wounded'.

If its momentum card is not on the edge of the momentum track when wounded, it shifts a number of steps equal to the number of remaining hits; if it reaches the edge, ignore the remainder.

Tactically, if there is only 1 target left, and it is not next to the Edge, then the last player should strongly consider taking the Plan action after powering and slotting Action cards.

Your advise was sound.